# Inconsistent values in numpy fft2 function

Tags: python, numpy, fft, highpass-filter

I found that inconsistent results appear while applying numpy.fft.fft2 function.

This is my code

```
img = cv2.imread('task2_sample_small.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
th=3
r, c = img.shape
y, x = np.mgrid[:r, :c]
hp_filter = np.where(np.sqrt((y - r // 2) ** 2 + (x - c // 2) ** 2) <= th, 0, 1)

fm_img = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(img))
fm_img  = abs(fm_img).astype(np.int)*hp_filter

h_img = abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(fm_img)))
fm_h_img = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft2(h_img))
fm_h_img = abs(fm_h_img).astype(np.int)

print(fm_img.sum() - fm_h_img.sum())
```

As you can see, what I did is just

(image) -> fft -> fftshift -> apply filter(*) -> ifftshift -> ifft -> (new_image) -> fft -> fftshift (*)

I computed the difference between two asterisk points which should be the same.

Because the only thing between two points is just restoration of it.

However, they have quite a huge difference.

Really weird thing is that if I don't apply filter or other filter the difference is only a portion.

For example, if I apply

```
hp_filter = np.where(np.sqrt((y - r // 2) ** 2 + (x - c // 2) ** 2) <= th, 1, 0)
```

which is low-pass filter, I got same results.

Literally I got weird results only when I apply high-pass filter.

What's the wrong point???

What causes this inconsistent result??

===========================

Actual Differences are below

If I apply low-pass filter
(hp_filter = np.where(np.sqrt((y - r // 2) ** 2 + (x - c // 2) ** 2) <= th, 1, 0))

fm_img is

[image]

fm_h_img is

[image]

However,

if I apply high-pass filter(hp_filter = np.where(np.sqrt((y - r // 2) ** 2 + (x - c // 2) ** 2) <= th, 0, 1))

fm_img is

[image]

fm_h_img is

[image]

Comment: It could be just me but, having re-read your question three times, I am still not sure what _exactly_ the problem is.  (You might want to consider being more specific when you say "huge difference", "weird results", "inconsistent results" — these descriptions are much too vague.)

Comment: I agree with @NPE, but looking at your code, if you convert floats to ints, isn't there always some accuracy lost?

Comment: Sorry guys, I appended the results

Comment: Just glancing at your code, but you seem to be taking absolute values all over the place. This typically throws away "half the information" so you cannot hope to get back to your starting point afterwards.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yeah I thought that could be a problem. But I totally cannot understand why only high-pass filter makes problems. Actually, low-pass and high-pass have no difference but the location of zeros and ones.

Comment: Well, since your original image presumably has only nonneg pixel values, the ft will have a rather dominant constant mode. If your filter has the right symmetries (i.e. if it is the ft of a real filter) the back transform will be real, so if the filter (after backtransform) leaves all pixels positive, the abs will do no harm. Now the low pass preserves the constant mode which will lift all pixels into nonneg territory. The high pass kills the constant mode, leaving you with a zero mean signal, so half of your mass will be negative and flipped by the abs. And that is where your roundtrip breaks